# Running the "migrate.exe" for entity framework 6.0.2 migrations in Windows 2003 and XP "Not a valid win32 application" exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Our product needs to be compatible with versions of windows including Server 2003 and XP.

We have code first entity framework projects with various migrations.

We are deploying these migrations to create or update a database using the "migrate.exe", file version 6.0.21211.0, supplied in entity framework 6.0.2 nuget package.

When using XP itself with visual studio 2010 or Windows 7 with visual studio 2013 to install the package every time we run "migrate.exe", on an xp or server 2003 machine, we are getting a "not a valid win32 application" exception.

Is there a good reason why "migrate.exe" will not run on windows xp and windows server 2003 other than the fact they are operating systems that nobody really wants to support any more?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve this issue by downloading the source code for 6.0.2 version of entity framework, un-signing it in properties, then building it through .net 4.0 and not 4.5 by changing the solution configurations to Release40.

Source code can be found here:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/7648d33dfb53589d9c32b605c61758a5a6c0b80b

I found it quite difficult to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have .NET Framework installed on the machines where it fails.

(As a side note I believe both XP and 2003 go out of support soon so you may want to upgrade your environment...)

Comment: As I said in the question, I have used XP with visual studio 2010 on it to actually install the nuget package for entity framework and it still produces a migrate.exe with the not a valid win32 application exception. I have .NET framework installed. XP and 2003 going out of support soon or not has nothing to do with this issue or question.

Comment: "XP and 2003 going out of support soon or not has nothing to do with this issue" - I don't agree with this - since the problem happens only on XP and 2003 and they are going out of support very soon you will be better off if you move to a newer system and your problem should be solved because you indicated that things work on newer systems.

Comment: Sorry Pawel but its our customers that insist to use xp and 2003 and not us. So unless we want to lose all the dosh that they pay us to support their archaic systems, we will have to support them.